# How to add an if statement to a input tag in php

Tags: php

I am trying to add this if statement

```
<?php 
 if( wc_memberships_is_user_member( null, 3171 ) ) {
                                                                        
}
?>
```

to work with this code

```
<input id="facebook" class="form-control" type="url" name="user[facebook]" value="<?php echo !empty($facebook) ? esc_attr($facebook) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_html_x('Enter your facebook url', 'placeholder', 'direo'); ?>" />
```

and i am ruining it like so

```
 <?php 
if( wc_memberships_is_user_member( null, 3171 ) ) {
<input id="facebook" class="form-control" type="url" name="user[facebook]" value="<?php echo !empty($facebook) ? esc_attr($facebook) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_html_x('Enter your facebook url', 'placeholder', 'direo'); ?>" />
}
?>
```

But a I am getting error :

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in the line that starts
> with  "<input id="facebook"

what am i doing wrong, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't place html elements inside php, you need to end your php code before the html element and start php again after it.

```
<?php 
if( wc_memberships_is_user_member( null, 3171 ) ) {
?>
<input id="facebook" class="form-control" type="url" name="user[facebook]" value="<?php echo !empty($facebook) ? esc_attr($facebook) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_html_x('Enter your facebook url', 'placeholder', 'direo'); ?>" />
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank  you very much it works